# Dial FTTH from 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pppoe

I have a Fibre to home (FTTH) connection. I can connect using ethernet cable from the ONU/ONT. But I don't know how to dial using the ID and password the ISP has given to me. Currently I use a WiFi router for dialing. I think it is safe to say that I need to dial through PPoE. I am using 18.04.

If possible, please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Check the WAN settings in your router. Look for connection type, and once selected, you'll see a place for ID/password.

Comment: I am trying to skip the router and dial through laptop using ethernet. Thanks.

Comment: See if my quick answer helps. Report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `terminal`, type `nm-connection-editor`. That brings you to this window...

[image]

Hit the `+` button...

[image]

Choose connection type...

[image]

Fill in required fields... hover over any field with the mouse cursor to get help...

**Update #1:**

Be sure to select the auto-connect checkbox in the General tab.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104802/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-dial-ftth-from-18-04).